# How to test "Timer code" in a GWTTestCase?

Tags: javascript, gwt, timer

I am writing code using GWT, and I have created a java.util.Timer *emulation*, which I could like to *test*. In Java, I would create a Timer, fire a task on it, wait until the task was executed, and then return from successfully the unit test method (or fail, after some timeout expired).

I don't know much about JavaScript (which is why I use GWT), but I have seen examples using the JavaScript "native" timer functions setTimeout()/setInterval(), where the handler/callback, *used a flag to make sure it was not called "while executing"*. In other words, some example said/implied that it is *possible* that while the callback/handler takes long to execute, it then gets *called again*, as the interval ran out once more. And so the examples used some flag, which the callback checked to make sure it does nothing if the last call to it did not end yet.

This made me assume that I can use setInterval() (indirectly, through GWT), to get some callback to be executed *while my code is waiting*. Since there is no "sleep" in JavaScript, I used a "busy loop" instead, but the callback never got executed.

So, is it that my assumption about "async callback" is wrong (sometimes, always?), or that the GWT Timer class (or htmlunit itself) somehow prevents this behavior (idk how the GWT Timer is implemented internally)?

And more importantly, how can I then test my java.util.Timer emulation in a GWTTestCase, if any TimerTask I create within a test method call simply won't execute until the test method call returned?

In the "real application", there will be a "game loop", and the timer tasks are free to run between the game loop cycles.

GWT code is something like:

```
public class TimerTest extends GWTTestCase {
    public void testScheduleLong() {
        final Timer timer = new Timer("test");
        final boolean[] marker = new boolean[] { false };
        new com.google.gwt.user.client.Timer() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                marker[0] = true;
            }
        }.schedule(10);

        assertFalse("marker[0]", marker[0]);
        double value = Long.MAX_VALUE;
        // Waste time, to see if marker changes
        final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (!marker[0] && (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < 1000)) {
            value = Math.sqrt(value);
            if (value > 1) {
                value = Long.MAX_VALUE;
            }
        }
        assertTrue("marker[0]", marker[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think You can't use `java.util.Timer` at client side in GWT.

Comment: @Braj I think you missed this part: "I have created a java.util.Timer emulation"; I have created a "super-source" for the "missing" JRE java.util.Timer class, as Google themselves have done for many JRE classes. The JRE emulation in GWT is so thin, that you can't port any significant *existing* project to GWT without additional JRE emulation classes. GWT itself provides their own Timer class; it's just that it uses a different API, and therefore forces user code to become dependent on GWT. A java.util.Timer emulation allows me to remove the explicit dependency on GWT, in "shared code".

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right.

Comment: So far, I have found this: http://sinonjs.org/docs/#clock which just might work, but it is a JS solution, and would have to be wrapped to work with GWT, and might mess up GWT itself. I'm waiting for a real answer before I try that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a comment for @ColinAlworth, which basically answered this question in a comment on another question, I found there is support for testing timers: [GWTTestCase.delayTestFinish(int timeoutMillis) + finishTest()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/junit/client/GWTTestCase.html#delayTestFinish%28int%29)