# How to "process pending events in queue" in GWT?

Tags: javascript, gwt

I am trying to solve [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23162539/how-to-test-timer-code-in-a-gwttestcase) by myself, since so far it was not answered. The goal was to create a Timer "task", and *synchronously wait for it to complete*. I have moved beyond busy-waiting into blocked-waiting using an XHR request on a "slow" (controllable delay) URL. But while I don't waste CPU anymore, the pending events are still not processed.

I think what I really need, is to do a loop that just tell GWT/JavaScript to process all "pending events" in the event queue, until my Timer events have been executed. There seems to be a way to do this in *Firefox* using something like this:

```
// Since FF3, we'll have to ask for user permission to execute XPCOM objects.
netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalXPConnect");
// Get the current thread.
var thread = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/thread-manager;1"]
.getService(Components.interfaces.nsIThreadManager).currentThread;
// Create an inner property to be used later as a notifier.
this.delayed = true;
// Execute "this.delayed = false" after it finishes.
setTimeout("this.delayed = false;", millis);
// Keep looping until "this.delayed = false"
while (this.delayed) {
    // This code will not freeze your browser
    thread.processNextEvent(true);
}
```

But this won't work in a GWTTestCase (htmlunit); so, my question is:

**Is there something like thread.processNextEvent() in GWT?**

Please take into consideration this, before answering:

1. I am creating a *unit test*.
2. This will never ever get executed either in the client browser or the server.
3. Therefore the "best practice is to use async code" advice is *not relevant* here.
4. Even if "use async code" was relevant, it does not help me at all, since *JUnit-style tests do not support async code testing* (at least not in a single-threaded environment!).

Comment: GWT JUnits definitely support async code, since so many test cases rely on it. The `GWTTestCase` class has two methods that you will find useful: `delayTestFinish(int)` and `finishTest()`.

Comment: @ColinAlworth Thank you. This solved my initial question.